# In the R's Kohonen package for self organizing maps, what does the `codes` value of the som object represent?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining, som

I'm generating a self-organizing map in R using the [kohonen](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kohonen/kohonen.pdf) package. However, when looking at the documentation, I cannot find a clear understanding of what the `codes` property of the `som` object represents.

The documentation only states:

> codes: a matrix of code vectors.

What is a matrix of code vectors in this context?

Comment: I've edited this question, I think it's safe to take off hold now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works like other SOM packages do, I believe the code value you mention refers to *codebook vectors*. Here's a good resource that explains how those work:

> The codebook vectors themselves represent prototypes (points) within
>   the domain, whereas the topological structure imposes an ordering
>   between the vectors during the training process.

From http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/neural/som.html

I would recommend reading the original paper that accompanied the kohnen package, which you can find here: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v021i05/v21i05.pdf

It provides quite a bit more detail than the R-docs.

Comment: Thank you so much! The original paper clarified a lot of things for me.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but I was just wondering how can the code book vector relate back to the original data we feed into the SOM during the training process?

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864333/identifying-points-by-color